# Resize Image using Opencv Python and preserving the quality

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, image-resizing

I would like to resize images using OpenCV python library.
It works but the quality of the image is pretty bad.

I must say, I would like to use these images for a photo sharing website, so the quality is a must.

Here is the code I have for the moment:

```
[...]

_image = image
height, width, channels = _image.shape
target_height = 1000
scale = height/target_height
_image = cv2.resize(image, (int(width/scale), int(height/scale)), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
cv2.imwrite(local_output_temp_file,image, (cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 100))
[...]
```

I don't know if there are others parameters to be used to specify the quality of the image.

Thanks.

Comment: This is all that basic opencv can do as far as I know. How much is the original size? By how much are you scaling up?

Comment: Are you scaling up or down?

Comment: I'm scaling down

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [`imutils.resize`](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils#resizing) to resize an image while maintaining aspect ratio. You can adjust based on desired `width` or `height` to upscale or downscale. Also when saving the image, you should use a lossless image format such as `.tiff` or `.png`. Here's a quick example:

Input image with shape `250x250`

[image]

Downscaled image to `100x100`

[image]

Reverted image back to `250x250`

[image]

```
import cv2
import imutils

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
resized = imutils.resize(image, width=100)
revert = imutils.resize(resized, width=250)

cv2.imwrite('resized.png', resized)
cv2.imwrite('original.png', image)
cv2.imwrite('revert.png', revert)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use more accurate interpolation techniques like `cv2.INTER_CUBIC` or `cv2.INTER_LANCZOS64`. Try also switching to `scikit-image`. Docs are better and lib is more reach in features. It has 6 modes of interpolation to choose from:

- 0: Nearest-neighbor
- 1: Bi-linear (default)
- 2: Bi-quadratic
- 3: Bi-cubic
- 4: Bi-quartic
- 5: Bi-quintic