# How to change the size of an image in Azure's custom vision service?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, object-detection-api, microsoft-custom-vision

I want to train model by using custom vision but when i add images in custom vision. Custom vision convert resize my image into (512,512). If there is any option so that i can set limit like (2000,2000) in custom vision.

Answer (score 0):

> If there is any option so that i can set limit like (2000,2000) in custom vision.

Yes, you can use [`imutils.resize()`](https://github.com/PyImageSearch/imutils#resizing) to resize the image to required dimensions.

For example:

```
import cv2
import imutils

image = cv2.imread('test.png')
resized = imutils.resize(image, width=2000)
revert = imutils.resize(resized, width=2000)

cv2.imwrite('testresized.png', resized)
cv2.imwrite('testoriginal.png', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

You can refer to [Crop the center for the specific input size for the model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/export-model-python#crop-the-center-for-the-specific-input-size-for-the-model), [Resize Image using Opencv Python and preserving the quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59246231/resize-image-using-opencv-python-and-preserving-the-quality) and [Resize an image with a max width and height, using openCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64609524/resize-an-image-with-a-max-width-and-height-using-opencv)